# Generating data on the fly for consumption by Media Foundation

Tags: c++, windows, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to feed dynamically generated data into a Media Foundation Source Reader by using an in-memory stream as the source stream:

```
 InMemoryRandomAccessStream^ memstream = ref new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
 IRandomAccessStream^ pInputStream = (IRandomAccessStream^)memstream;
 ComPtr<IMFByteStream> pInputByteStream;
 MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStreamEx((IUnknown*)pInputStream, &pInputByteStream);
 hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream(pInputByteStream.Get(), NULL, &m_pSourceReader);
 // last line FAILS, “The handle is invalid.”
```

However, I am stuck by the error above.  Why isn't this valid, and how do I correct it?  Alternatively, is there a better way to create a media foundation pipeline with dynamic data?

Answer (score 0):

this used to work for me:

```
void MyClass::Init(Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStream^ stream)
{
    ComPtr<IUnknown> pStreamUnk = reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(stream);
    ComPtr<IMFByteStream> pMFStream;
    hr = ::MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStreamEx(pStreamUnk.Get(), &pMFStream);

    hr = ::MFCreateSourceReaderFromByteStream(pMFStream.Get(), NULL, &m_pSourceReader);
}
```

but this was for a file stream.
for your case, your memory stream might not have all the data needed for the pipeline.

A better solution is to implement a media source. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371827(v=vs.85).aspx (GeometricSource & Mpeg1Source)